# Search Bar in Outlook Ribbon

Tags: c#, search, ribbon, outlook-addin

I have to make a search field in my Ribbon of Outlook with C#. 
This field should search a SQL Database Table for people. 
Thats all no problem to make the code, the problems are the available fields of the toolbox in the ribbon. 
For standard you can only use a "Edid Box" or a "Drop Down" field. Both have only the eventhandler "On Text Change" and so you have to press enter before the code is started. 
And what I want is a search like google on each Key Press a new drop down array, who shows the results.
I tried to get a "normal" Windows Forms Text Box in the ribbon, but everything I tried failed. I don´t know if I make it wrong or if it not possible.

Someone an idea how can I make this search filed. I would also take a completely other way.

Thanks for your answer.